# Max execution time unlimited and dynamic background scripts in php

Tags: php

I have a scenario like i need to send mail for 1000 users each with a time interval of 5 min.

I Created a php script to trigger mail function inside a loop with sleep() function like below

```
for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
   sleep(300);
   mail();
}
```

I get time out error and i tried to increase max_execution_time, then also i get the same error, Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Why not send it to eg. 100 people each run and then use a cronjob to trigger it every 5 min and then have it send to the next 100?

Comment: Use a CRON job, there are no limits on PHP Execution time when you use PHP CLI

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`

Comment: This is the error i getting @ Charlotte ,Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Comment: And you run this from command line or web browser?

Comment: But Cron Job will keeps on executing the scripts in a scheduled manner , i need to trigger this mail only when i needed @ Edpdax , is there any Dynamic Cron option i can set ?

Comment: @Will i use Web Browser to send mail using php script

Comment: The browser won't hold the connection alive for long enough. You need to run something like this in a process on the server via the `php` commandline shell. Alternatively, you could make the webpage only send one batch of mail, and hit the URL from `curl` every 5 minutes.

Comment: @Will thankyou for the reply i will try that method